# Disable c++11 features in Visual Studio2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to disable C++11 features when writing code in Visual Studio 2013?

I want my code to also compile on older compilers like VS 2008.

I tried to change via:
`project->properties->general->platform tool-set`, and change `"Visual Studio 2013 (v120)"`
to something older, but this is the only thing I have in the drop down menu there.

Comment: Why not simply don't use any C++11 (or newer) features?

Comment: im new to c++ , i cant tell for every feature if its a  c++11 feature.

Comment: Then may I recommend [a good reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)? It shows clearly what features and classes and functions are C++03, C++11 or C++14. However, the best way is to use an older (without C++11 or higher support) to compile your program.

Comment: For g++/clang, there are ABI differences between C++98/03 and C++11, hence linking objects compiled with a differing C++ standard is illegal. Don't know about VS.

Comment: Why don't you just use VS2008?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need compatibility with VS2013?

Comment: Just don't use C++11 feature - it's simple and good solution.

Comment: I thinks I will probably just use vs 2008 , its the best solution for me

Comment: Personally I'd say that the money to upgrade to VS2013 universally will dramatically pay itself off in terms of the productivity/maintainability gain granted by C++11...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have other versions of Visual Studio installed then you can select the older tool set. This may help a little.

A better solution, IMHO, is to set up a continuous integration server that builds your code for all supported compilers, configurations and platforms. You will then get build breaks as soon as you do something that isn't supported. Ideally the CI server also runs all of your unit tests so that you also see if any of your configurations break your tests.

Comment: I installed VS 2008 side by side with vs 2013, and know i can choose vs2008 from the drop down . that helped

Answer (score 10):

You can't.

Unfortunately you can not disable C++11 features and downgrade to C++03 or C++98 in Visual Studio. You can see what features belongs to C++11 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), try not to use them.

However a better choice is to use older VS versions to make sure that you don't use any new feature.

Personally, I use MinGW/GCC in Windows and I can disable C++11 by using a compiler switch `-std=c++03`, `-std=c++98` or not using `-std=c++11`.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 introduces two new switches (/std:c++14 and /std:c++latest) to give you control over the version of the C++ programming language you want to use in your projects. In this update, if you specify a language version that isn’t any of those, the compiler will ignore the switch (with a warning) and default to C++14.

see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/standards-version-switches-in-the-compiler/

Answer (score 0):

Either use a compiler which allows to set the used standard explicitly (Clang and GCC allow to choose the standard version) or make yourself familiar with the changes in C++11 so you can avoid them in your code.

If you need a reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/ The sides show clearly in which standard version a certain feature was introduced.

Comment: It is pretty easy to mistakenly use C++11 features when trying to write C++03 code.  For example, a std::vector in C++03 requires that elements be [Copy-Assignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyAssignable) and [Copy-Constructable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible), while C++11 removes those restrictions.  So in some cases saying "avoid C++11 features" is as useless as a statement as "avoid writing bugs".

Answer (score 0):

Configure Visual Studio to use a different compiler that does not support C++11 features.  Intellisense will still show C++11 features, but you can catch issues on a local compile before checking it in.

[How to use GCC with Microsoft Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio)