# How to enable C++98 compiling in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

How to enable C++98 compiling in Visual Studio 2019?
because I want to compile an old project and the old project need a c++ 98 environment.

Comment: try this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371985/change-use-older-c-version-in-visual-studio)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23386938/2864740

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language > Conformance mode = No.

Answer (score 4):

In short: The compiler does not support standards switches for C++98, C++03, or C++11.[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019)

**each compiler support default C++ version:**

C++98 (ISO/IEC 14882:1998) is the first edition.

C++03 (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) is the second edition.

C++11 is the third edition.

**C++14 is the fourth edition. (min version for Visual Studio 2019)**

C++17 is the fifth edition.

You can use an older toolset, you must first install that version of Visual Studio, and then modify the "Configuration Properties->General->Platform Toolset" and set it to the appropriate Visual Studio version.

To find the right version for your code: [Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019)

Alternatively, install some recent GCC variant - 4.9 or better; or some recent 
Clang/LLVM (perhaps thru cygwin, mingw, or by installing a Linux distribution).
Then compile with g++ -std=c++98 or clang++ -std=c++98.