# Android.mk: How to check if a module already exists

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm trying to generate Android.mk files automatically for an existing build environment. This environment has many libraries linking to each other and also possibly linking to 3rd party libs (like boost).

Let's say I have `libA` using boost.
My goal being to build both `libA` and `libB` by running ndk-build from libB folder.

So I generate this Android.mk for `libA`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Import boost
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := boost_atomic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1/lib/libboost_atomic.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# libA:
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libA.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1

# boost import:
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fexceptions -frtti
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += boost_atomic

# build libA:
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now I have `libB` using both `boost` and `libA`. `libB`'s `Android.mk` is very similar to `libA`'s except I added the import of `libA` file as below:

```
# Import libA
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libA
include ../../libA/jni/Android.mk
```

When I try to make `libB`, I'm being reported:

```
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'boost_atomic' in ../../libA/jni/Android.mk.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by ../../libA/jni/Android.mk.
B:/Android/android-ndk-r11b/build//../build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android
 NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

Is there a way for me to check if `boost_atomic` is already defined (like `if (exists boost_atomic)`) to make sure it gets defined once only? Or should I suffix all the names (ending up with `boost_system_for_libA` and `boost_system_for_libB`) to prevent the conflict? Or any other alternative?

Comment: It *is* possible to avoid duplicate definitions of modules, but in your case, for boost it would be easier to simply add `LOCAL_LDLIBS += ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1/lib/libboost_atomic.a` instead of adding it as LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES

Comment: @AlexCohn: Would be a nice fix. Will try it tomorrow. Can I do the same for shared libraries? Because I guess I'll have the same problem if having `libC` using `libB` and `libA`, `libA` will end up being defined twice (imported both by `libB` and `libC`) when I'll compile `libC`.

Comment: No, this won't work for non-prebuilt libs, and shared libs should not be specified in LDLIBS anyways. But usually it's easy to include your Android.mk files according to hierarchy of subdirectories. This avoids duplication.

Comment: @AlexCohn: Thanks, `LOCAL_LDLIBS += ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1/lib/libboost_atomic.a` will give `non-system libraries in linker`warning. How to get rid of this warning? (Tried simply `LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1/lib/libboost_atomic.a` but it won't work).

Comment: You can ignore this warning. It is only relevant for shared libs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an NDK function `$(modules_get_list)`. Relying on it, your **libA/jni/Android.mk** file may look as follows:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include ../../boost/Android.mk

# libA:
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libA.cpp

# boost import:
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += boost_atomic

# build libA:
$(if $(call set_is_member,$(modules-get-list),$(LOCAL_MODULE)),\
    ,$(eval include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)))
```

and **boost/Android.mk** file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Import boost
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := boost_atomic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1/lib/libboost_atomic.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1
LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fexceptions -frtti
$(if $(call set_is_member,$(modules-get-list),$(LOCAL_MODULE)),\
    ,$(eval include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY))
```

Finally, **libB/jni/Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include ../../boost/Android.mk
include ../../libA/jni/Android.mk

# libB:
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libB
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libB.cpp

# boost import:
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += boost_atomic

# build libA:
$(if $(call set_is_member,$(modules-get-list),$(LOCAL_MODULE)),\
    ,$(eval include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)))
```

I prefer not to have duplicate definitions for 3rd party prebuilt libs, like boost, but rather to use a separate **Android.mk** definition for each, and `include` it whenever necessary. This way, I have one place to change if the external library is updated.

**Update:** if you don't like `$(if …)` syntax, you may use

```
ifeq ($(filter $(modules-get-list),$(LOCAL_MODULE)),)
    include $(BUILD_…_LIBRARY)
endif
```

instead.

Comment: Nice, I did set my own variable to track duplicate definition, but it makes the code complex (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40173692/android-makefiles-how-to-early-return). I'll try your solution, but only in a few weeks (when coming back from vacation).

Comment: Did not work. I tried to call `ifndef $(modules_get_list).$(LOCAL_MODULE)` just after I do `include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)` and this is evaluated to `true`. Did I miss something?

Comment: My apologies, this is `$(modules-get-list)`. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Alex. How can I put this in a regular if statement? `ifeq ($(call set_is_member,$(modules-get-list),$(LOCAL_MODULE)),true)` fails, as `$(call set_is_member,$(modules-get-list),$(LOCAL_MODULE))` is evaluated to `T` not `true` (sorry, I'm not very familiar with those makefile syntax.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex Cohn mentioned, one may fix that by replacing:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := boost_atomic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1/lib/libboost_atomic.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

...

# boost import:
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fexceptions -frtti
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += boost_atomic
```

By simply:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1/lib/libboost_atomic.a
```

This works but:

- Introduces a compilation warning:

  WARNING:/Users/jwalton/Android-CryptoPP/jni/Android.mk:prng:
      non-system libraries in linker flags: -lcryptopp -lstlport_shared
      This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES
      or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the
      current module
- Won't work for shared 3rd party libraries

So I finally fixed this my adding a new mk file specific to `libA`, `libB`:

**`libA`'s `Android.mk` is now:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Import boost
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := boost_atomic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1/lib/libboost_atomic.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include libA.mk
```

**`libA`'s `libA.mk` is now:**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# libA:
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libA.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ../dev/libcpp/boost/1.60.1

# boost link:
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -fexceptions -frtti
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES += boost_atomic

# build libA:
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**`libB`'s `libB.mk` now has:**

```
# Import libA
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libA
include ../../libA/jni/libA.mk
```

So that it imports `libA` without importing `boost` (also defined in `libB`'s `Android.mk`).

Then, no warning and it compiles smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to generate Android.mk files automatically for an existing
>   build environment. This environment has many libraries linking to each
>   other and also possibly linking to 3rd party libs (like boost).

Why not to use [standalone NDK toolchains](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) instead of painful coping with `Android.mk` files? Sounds like standalone toolchains are ideally suitable in your situation.

Comment: @jpo38 Yes, they do. _... for an existing build environment ..._ - seems like you have some makefiles / build scripts already, don't you?

Comment: Yes, am using Visual Studio. It also natively supports Android target but only for Professional edition, I'm using Express edition...

Comment: @jpo38 Visual Studio is not my cup of tea, but anyway I believe that even Express edition lets you to use custom toolchain somehow. Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14819449/2878070) would give you an idea.

Comment: I'll have a look. But, honestly, generating the makefiles manually from CMake is not such a big deal. I got it working with only 100 lines of CMake code being written (already did that some time ago to generate QtCreator project files from CMake, as importing CMake in QtCreator was not working properly for me). And I fully control what's happening...