# How to configure external compiler like gcc +14 with microsoft visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I want to use debugging quality of microsoft visual studio and its built in compiler does not allow me to declare array like int a[n] giving errors like it should be constant value and thus my time is being wasted on dynamically allocating it. Also I am unable to include libraries like bits/stdc++.h

I am using windows 10. Please tell me how can I configure my compiler.For my purpose I will be having just one cpp file.

My main purpose will be to solve questions from spoj,codeforces etc

Comment: "*its built in compiler does not allow me to declare array like int a[n] giving errors like it should be constant value*" C++ doesn't let you do that. It's a C feature that GCC ports into C++.

Comment: Are you seriously complaining that VC++ does not allow you to use a **non-standard** feature you shouldn't be using in the first place?

Comment: Not be a jerk, but it probably took you more time to submit the question then to simply type `std::vector<int> a; a.resize(n);`

Comment: @linuxuser27 why not `std::vector<int> buf(n);`?!

Comment: The visual-studio-2012 and visual-c++-2010 tags are unnecessary.  You are talking about how to implement a compiler in Visual Studio 2017.  You should get rid of those tags and replace them with visual-studio-2017.  Tags need to refer to the question at hand.

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius Duh :)

Comment: `bits/stdc++.h` is not a "library" but an **internal** GCC header file whose name or path should never appear in your own code. Including it is a terrible practice which I think has appeared about one year ago and which just isn't going away anymore. I wonder where people are picking it up.

Comment: @linuxuser27 I know that but ehat if I want to use gcc compiler in visual studio ? How can I configure that?

Comment: Don't write code with VLAs, please. Just stick to standard C++.

Comment: @AnkitJain Making Visual Studio use another C/C++ compiler is a non-trivial process. I seem to recall there being a way to use MinGW in VS, but I can't really recall specifics. If you are looking to practice and solve online questions I second JesperJuhl advice and use standard C++ so you can learn the language which should be compiler agnostic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use GCC with Microsoft Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio)

Answer (score 1):

There are three different options.

1. Create a Custom Build Tool
2. Makefile Project
3. Cross-Platform Development

Theres a similar question with a good answer with the explanation of my Options
[How to use GCC with Microsoft Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio)