# How to use g++ compiler in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++

Cant find any easy way to compile c++ projects under g++ in visual studio 2019. All I can find are tutorials for Visual Studio Code, not the full Visual Studio.

Comment: Did you look at: https://www.instructables.com/id/Compile-Using-GNU-GCC-from-Visual-Studio/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GCC with Microsoft Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio)

Comment: Highlight  **[How to use GCC with Microsoft Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio)**

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you can add g++ in External Tools.

[image]