# Compile and Build commands in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, mingw

how to set compile and build in visual studio 2019 for c++ like 
compile  - g++ -std=c++17 -Wshadow -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -O2 -Wno-unused-result
build - g++ -std=c++17 -Wshadow -Wall -o "%e" "%f" -g -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
not visual studio code (vscode) but for the Visual Studio 2017 IDE using mingw compiler

Comment: So you want to use the mingw compiler with Visual Studio 2017 instead of microsoft's compliler.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the following: [How to use GCC with Microsoft Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio)