# How to enable the "C++ Compiler" option in Microsoft Visual Studio to set up the C++ compiler to be g++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, compiler-options

I know the question "how to use g++ in VS" has been asked several times in a variety of ways, and I have read through many posts, but only one solution seemed feasible to my team and I given the requirements we have and the limited time we have to figure this out. That solution would be the one in this link: [How to use GCC with Microsoft Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio) (the second answer) which shows how to set up the c++ compiler to be g++ using the Microsoft Visual Studio's GUI.

Our problem is that not any of us see that option in our respective GUIs. We even tried with the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 and we keep not seeing it. So, my question now is: how to enable the "C++ Compiler" option in Visual Studio so that I can then use g++ to be that compiler?

Comment: if you read a little, it also mentions to "install the Linux C++ Workload"

Comment: and [Use any C++ Compiler with Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/)