# Xcode C gnu11 to visual studio 2017

Tags: c, xcode

is there an easy way to compile C code in visual studio using gnu11?
I wrote the code on Xcode and it works perfectly fine, but doesn't even compile on visual studio, the main problem is that I defined an integer named "size", which takes the length of a string and then defined an array with the size "size".
works perfectly normal in Xcode, can't even compile in visual studio.

`int size = strlen(input);`

`int sorted_input[size];`

Comment: The Microsoft compiler doesn't support VLAs (variable length arrays). Replace `sorted_input[size]` with `sorted_input[1000]` and it should compile.

Comment: Otherwise maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio) helps

Comment: There's always `malloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I did put the size 1000 and now its crashing because its accessing out of range array, I'll try using the malloc. thanks for both of you.

Comment: @BaselMassarweh my suggestion was for being it able to be compiled, of course if `strlen(input)` is larger than 1000 you'll have a problem. If you use `malloc` don't forget to free the allocated memory. Otherwise you still have [`_alloca`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=msvc-160) which does basically the exact same thing as VLAs: `int *sorted_input = _alloca(size * sizeof(*sorted));`