# CL.EXE to gcc compiler

Tags: windows, gcc, cl.exe

I am using Visual Studio 2019 community version in windows. Currently cl.exe compiler is used. But i want to replace the cl.exe compiler with gcc compiler.
More clearly, i want to get gcc compiled output from visual studio.

Please help me.

Comment: GCC is not supported by Visual Studio. You're going to have to clobber something together.

Comment: using Clang in MSVC would be much easier

Comment: @phuclv Could you  please explain me how to configure clang in MSVC? Via that, can i able to get gcc compiled output?

Comment: obviously not, Clang is an entirely different compiler https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/. GCC is supported ([Use any C++ Compiler with Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/use-any-c-compiler-with-visual-studio/)) but it's more difficult to configure, compared to the built-in Clang support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GCC with Microsoft Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768073/how-to-use-gcc-with-microsoft-visual-studio)

Comment: Though, what is the *real* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @IInspectable , I just want to compile via gcc compiler in visual studio.

Comment: You're going to have to convince MSBuild to use GCC then. There's a pretty steep learning curve, and virtually no useful documentation available. Plus, MSBuild is all-around hostile to building native code. It's really only useful for .NET, but it is the build system integrated into Visual Studio.

Comment: Visual Studio is built around the MSVC compiler.
But what a lot of people are doing is using MinGW-w64 GCC from Visual Studio Code. Maybe it's worth checking that out?